# Is it possible to CONCAT a range only for the cells that contain text?

Tags: excel-formula, concatenation

I have data that consists of multiple jobs, each consisting of lines of comment text, with each line in a separate cell. I have set up a formula that extracts the data and organises it more efficiently, and now I'm trying to combine them into one cell, but still on different lines, so they can be transferred to other software (namely Business Central) easily. I've managed to get `=CONCAT(Sheet5!E3:E40&CHAR(10))`, which collects the lines into one cell separated by carriage breaks (these aren't visible in the cell itself, but when the cell is copied and pasted into, say, Notepad, it works).

My issue is that the number of comment lines in a job can vary a lot. I've extended the organising formula to cover more cells than I think I'm likely to need, but this results in up to 35 empty cells, which are being included in the `CONCAT()` as empty lines. I'm wondering if there's something I can put in the `CONCAT()`, around `Sheet5!E3:E40`, which will mean it only applies to cells in this range with text in (or, non-empty cells). I know there are ways to check if a cell is empty, but I'm blanking on how to actually apply it to the cell range without crossing over the `CONCAT()` argument and breaking that function.

Unfortunately, using `=(IF(Sheet5!E3:E11<>"",CONCAT(Sheet5!E2),""))` spills to make several copies of the `CONCAT()`ed cell, possibly because my organising formula *doesn't* spill, (at least, it's not doing it for me) so is simply copied to all of the cells individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click [image: wordwrap icon], which is the icon for Word Wrap and usually located in the Home menu, you can see the blank lines as you do in Notepad.

To remove them, place the `IF` **inside** the `CONCAT`. This returns a range for `CONCAT` to use.

```
=CONCAT(IF(A1:D2<>"",A1:D2&CHAR(10),""))
```

[image: output]

Comment: The problem is I need `CHAR(10)`s when there is text in the cells, to distinguish between comment lines; it's only the empty cells I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: @mattH; change of strategy!